# Get whole HTML of page included values of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to save whole page as HTML file included all already written values into inputs. I tried this:

```
$("#content").html();
```

but it wont save values from inputs.

```
$("#content").get(0).outerHTML;
$("#content").prop('outerHTML');
```

Works same but still not save values of inputs. I need function which save everything on the page.

Comment: The values of inputs are properties and do not affect the HTML. You would need to manually get all the values of any inputs and update them in the HTML string you build.

Comment: @rory `value` attribute is a part of HTML though ...

Comment: That's true, but it does not get updated directly when you change the value. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/LmxLygcf/. The value shown in the console will always be `foo` no matter what you set in the input.

Comment: True, but wouldn't it be easier to set the values to attributes instead of a complex string manipulation?

Comment: If the OP really wants to do that, then it would be a solution. This does sound like an XY problem though. Perhaps `clone()` would work too, although the OPs actual use case would be helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up each input values first:

```
$('#content input').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());//set up all the input values
});

var html = $('#content').html(); //now from here you can get input values
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$("html").html();
```

If you want to also capture the hmtl tags you could concatenate them to the html like this:

```
function getPageHTML() {
  return "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
}
```

you have save the inputs values in some variable like

```
 var input=$("#input-id").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

When an input is changed by the user it's `.value` is being changed. `.value` is not in the DOM, it's in the JS. So, what you need to do is transfer the `.value` to `value=` in order to be able to get it in the string. Here is how to accomplish it:

```
$('input').each(function(index, input){input.setAttribute('value', input.value)});
```

Now try to get the HTML ;)

PS: You could also modify the selector here, not to get all the inputs (like `type="password"`).